# APP Icon zooms on start and appears blurred on IOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode

When I launch my app, the app icon appears to zoom into the launch image on IOS 7.

I haven't upgraded my code to IOS 7 so my App runs in compatibility IOS 6 mode.

Unfortunately the icon (Dimension 114 x 114) when it gets stretched appears blurred for a moment. What can I do to prevent this from happing? Remember I cannot use any of IOS 7 features because for now I can only use Xcode 4.6.3?

Comment: You need to save the 57x57,114x114 and 120x120 size icons in the project . Why because iOS 7 takes 120x120 size icon .

Comment: My problem is that since Xcode 4.6.3 does not know IOS 7 I can not provide 1 120x120 size icon. It does not allow me to upload an icon with this size. But I am not ready to upgrade to XCode 5 yet

Comment: No dude try to add it to project with the icon.png name